# How do you stop screen sharing in Mac OS?

Tags: screen-sharing

I want to know how to stop screen sharing in Mac OS, once I've enabled it by clicking "share screen" in the dialogue that pops up.

I don't want to disable screen sharing, since I'd still like to allow future requests for sharing. I just want to terminate the current sharing session.

Comment: I think you can terminate the session from an icon that looks like a pair of binoculars that appears in the menu bar. This icon should only appear during a session. I'm not 100% sure since I'm not at my mac right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon in the menu bar with binoculars inside of a screen is definitely the way to disconnect.

Thanks to Chard Marmon for the answer in the comments of my question.

Comment: Please either mark your answer as the answer, or, in this case, ask @chad to post his comment as an answer and then mark his answer as accepted.